# How to specify the API version?

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

According to the [Azure DevOps Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1), the request URI has the following format:

```
https://{instance}[/{team-project}]/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}
```

Regarding the `api-version`:

> Every API request should include an api-version to avoid having your app or service break as APIs evolve.

I started using the [.NET client libraries for Azure DevOps Services (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) to manage dashboards programmatically.

I am able to connect to Azure DevOps using a Personal Access Token:

```
var credential = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PersonalAccessToken");

using (VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("...."), credential))
using (var client = connection.GetClient<DashboardHttpClient>())
{
     // ...
}
```

How can I specify the API version? Does it still make sense to do it, when using the [.NET client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API version is decided by the client libraries. You can confirm this by disassembling them (e.g. using ILSpy).

For example, in the current stable release of `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client`, `DashboardHttpClientBase` has a `CreateDashboardAsnc` method that makes the following call:

```
this.SendAsync<Dashboard>(..., new ApiResourceVersion("4.1-preview.2"), ...);
```