# VssResourceNotFoundException: API resource location <GUID> is not registered on {tfs url} - c#

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to get the build information of a collection using **BuildHttpClient**. But it is throwing

> VssResourceNotFoundException: API resource location {GUIS} is not registered on http://tfsserver/tfs

The following code sample produces the error:

```
 var url = new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs");
 TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url);
 BuildHttpClient client = ttpc.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
 List<Build> builds = client.GetBuildsAsync().Result;
```

Comment: It might also be a problem with version
See my response in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299586/api-resource-location-is-not-registered/57789384#57789384

Answer (score 5):

You're specifying the location of your TFS server, but **not** the project collection. You need to specify a project collection in the URI.

Ex: `var url = new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");`